# prolog avg of list

Tags: prolog

I have the code that able to calculate the avg of a list, but the only problem is it has error when it is empty list. I want to return false when the list is empty. any hint?

```
avg( List, Avg ):- 
    sum( List, Sum ),
    length( List, Length), 
    Avg is Sum / Length.
```

Answer (score 3):

of course, dividing by zero isn't usually allowed. If (by convention) the average of 0 elements can be 0 a possible correction would be

```
avg( List, Avg ):- 
    sum( List, Sum ),
    length( List, Length), 
    (  Length > 0
    -> Avg is Sum / Length
    ;  Avg is 0
    ).
```

**edit** I tested in SWI-Prolog, replacing sum/2 by sumlist/2

```
avg( List, Avg ):-
    sumlist( List, Sum ),
    length( List, Length),
    (  Length > 0
    -> Avg is Sum / Length
    ;  Avg is 0
    ).
```

test:

```
?- avg([1,2,3],X).
X = 2.

?- avg([],X).
X = 0.
```

**edit** I'm sorry I overlooked that `false` is required on empty input list. Then a test if `Length > 0` is surely appropriate. The predicate will fail on that.

An alternative using library(aggregate):

```
?- L=[1,2,3,4,5], aggregate((count,sum(N)),member(N,L),(Count,SumN)), Ave is SumN/Count.
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
Count = 5,
SumN = 15,
Ave = 3.
```

Comment: could be sum/2 is undefined ? or your Prolog doesn't implements ->/2 ?. See my edit...

Comment: Oh, sorry, doing to much Lisp lately and read the `;` as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a condition that the list is not empty, for example:

```
average( List, Average ):- 
    sum( List, Sum ),
    length( List, Length ),
    Length > 0, 
    Average is Sum / Length.
```

This will cause the predicate to fail, which is appropriate since the average is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

avg( List, Avg/1 ):-

```
sumlist( List, Sum ),

length( List, Length),

(  Length > 0
-> Avg is Sum / Length
;  Avg is 0
).
```

you should divide the average by 1.
such as avg(List, Avg/1). I just copied it given in above comments and add avg/2.

Answer (score 0):

Use the accumulator, meaning, a counter to implement the arithmetic average could be helpful to understand how Prolog works.

```
mean([],0). % an empty list would have mean 0

mean(Xs,Mean):- % define the predicate with a list, and the mean output
  % pass the original list, mean output, and adds two counters
  % the counters should start at 0 for accumulation
  mean1(Xs,0,0,Mean). 

% base case, after recursion, the list would be empty
% the counter would accumulate the number of elements and
% the sum of the elements
mean1([],Count,Sum,Mean):- 
  Mean is Sum / Count.

% basic recursion to track the EleCount, plus 1 each time
% the Sum would add the X in the Xs each time, until Xs is empty
mean1([X|Xs],EleCount,Sum,Mean):-
  NewCount is EleCount + 1,
  NewSum is Sum + X,
  mean1(Xs,NewCount,NewSum,Mean).
```