# Prolog - average predicate: Arguments not sufficiently instantiated

Tags: list, functional-programming, prolog, instantiation-error

I have a list of cars (auto in german), where the first Variable is the license-plate and the second one the speed:

```
[auto(eu-ts884, 69), auto(dn-gh184, 64), auto(ac-lj123, 72)].
```

Now I try to write an average predicate but it fails with the error message:

> ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

My code so far:

```
durchschnitt([], 0, 0).
durchschnitt([auto(_, X)|Tail], L, Y):-
                        Y is S/L,
                        L > 0,
                        cardinal([auto(_, X)|Tail], L),
                        sumKilometer([auto(_, X)|Tail], S).


sumKilometer([], 0).
sumKilometer([auto(_, X)|Tail], Sum) :-
            sumKilometer(Tail, N),
            Sum is N + X.


cardinal([], 0).
cardinal([_|Tail], Result) :-
  cardinal(Tail, N),
  Result is N + 1.
```

My code is quite equivalent to that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756072/prolog-avg-of-list), although I cannot make out my mistake.

**Note**: `sumKilometer` and `cardinal` are working fine.

Comment: `?- L=[1,2,3,4,5], aggregate((count,sum(N)),member(N,L),(Count,SumN)), Ave is SumN/Count.
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
Count = 5,
SumN = 15,
Ave = 3.
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write:

```
durchschnitt([], 0, 0).
durchschnitt([auto(_, X)|Tail], L, Y):-
    Y is S/L,
    L > 0,
    cardinal([auto(_, X)|Tail], L),
    sumKilometer([auto(_, X)|Tail], S).
```

The first problem is that when you call `durchschnitt([auto(foo,2)],L,Y)`, **`L` is a free variable**. As a result, you **cannot calculate `Y is S/L`** since both `S` and `L` are unknown here.

You can however use:

```
durchschnitt([], 0, 0).
durchschnitt([auto(_, X)|Tail], L, Y):-
    cardinal([auto(_, X)|Tail], L),
    sumKilometer([auto(_, X)|Tail], S),
    Y is S/L.
```

So here you calculate the average **after both `L` and `S` are known**. Furthermore you do not unify the list with `[auto(_,X)|Tail]`, etc. A simple check like `A = [_|_]` is sufficient:

```
durchschnitt([], 0, 0).
durchschnitt(A, L, Y):-
    A = [_|_],
    cardinal(A, L),
    sumKilometer(A, S),
    Y is S/L.
```

This will also reduce the amount of time spent *packing* and *unpacking*.

## Sum, Length and Average all concurrently

You can construct a predicate that calculates the three all at the same time (so without looping twice over the list). You can simply use *accumulators*, like:

```
durchschnitt(A,L,Y) :-
    durchschnitt(A,0,0,L,Y).
```

Here the second and third element are the *running* sum and length respectively.

Now for `durchschnitt/5`, there are two cases. In the first case we have reached the end of the list, and we thus have to calculate the average and return it, like:

```
durchschnitt([],S,L,L,Y) :-
    (L \= 0
    -> Y is S/L
    ; Y = 0).
```

So we use an if-then-else to check if the length is something different than `0` (in the case there are no `auto`s in the list, we return `0` as average.

In the recursive case, we simple increment the *running length* and update the *running sum*, like:

```
durchschnitt([auto(_,Si)|T],RS,RL,L,Y) :-
    RSN is RS+Si,
    L1 is L+1,
    durchschnitt(T,RSN,L1,L,Y).
```

Or putting it together:

```
durchschnitt(A,L,Y) :-
    durchschnitt(A,0,0,L,Y).

durchschnitt([],S,L,L,Y) :-
    (L \= 0
    -> Y is S/L
    ; Y = 0).
durchschnitt([auto(_,Si)|T],RS,RL,L,Y) :-
    RSN is RS+Si,
    L1 is L+1,
    durchschnitt(T,RSN,L1,L,Y).
```